# Two dimensional array of objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers

I am migrating a scientific code from Java to C++. Please tell me:

a) What's wrong with the two functions?
b) How can I solve the problem? I can use the `int**` like a two dimensional array but not the `Agent**`.

I receive this error: *"No operator = matches this operand"*.

In normal C we could assign NULL to pointers. We could also use a `type**` like a two dimensional array (i.e. `a[i][j]`) (two dimensional space for `objectSpace` and `agentSpace` is allocated somewhere else).

```
    int** objectSpace;
    Agent** agentSpace;

    void Space::removeAgentAt(Point p)
    {
        agentSpace[p.x][p.y] = NULL;
    }

    void Space::putAgentTo(Agent agent, Point p)
    {
        agentSpace[p.x][p.y] = agent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it like this, for `Agent** agentSpace`, the first `*` gives you access to the first dimension of the array, the second `*` gives you access to the second dimension.

`Agent**` is a pointer to pointers - or in your case an array of pointers. When you attempted to do `agentSpace[p.x][p.y] = NULL`, you were trying to assign `NULL` in to what the compiler thinks is a full object of type `Agent` You need another level of indirection:

```
Agent*** agentSpace = 
    {
         { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 },
         { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 },
         { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

`agentSpace` is a pointer, and `agentSpace[p.x]` is a pointer, but `agentSpace[p.x][p.y]` is not a pointer.

C++ is not the same as Java; objects are (usually) referred to by value, not by reference.

Comment: Oli, I need to have an array of Agents and modify the array to show where in the space are the agents.

Could you possibly give a bit advise or kindly a solution?

Comment: @wmac do you know the dimensions of the array at compile time, or only at runtime? You are likely better off using a standard library container.

Comment: Unfortunately dimensions are unknown but the space is too large. It may contain 1000*1000 cells. I thought that's too much for containers.

Comment: @wmac if the dimensions are too large for a container of containers (vector of vectors seems to fit your use-case best) then they are too large for a dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `NULL` is just an alias for `0`. Unless you have coded conversion from integers to `Agent` objects, you can't assign `NULL` to an `Agent`.

One solution is to make a dummy `Agent` object, like `Agent AgentNone;` and use that instead of `NULL`. You might have to implement comparison operators if you want to check if an `Agent` object is equal to `AgentNone`.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need to define an assignment operator for your Agent class?

Answer (score 0):

To make the code easier to match against the original, provide the array dimensions:

```
int   objectSpace[100][200];   // but use the actual dimensions
Agent agentSpace[250][300];    // todo:  fix dimensions
```

Even better would be to use defined constants:

```
int   objectSpace[OS_X_MAX][OS_Y_MAX];
Agent agentSpace[AS_X_MAX][AS_Y_MAX];
```

If this is in a header file seen by all modules, then the code you have will work correctly.  If there are any places where one of these arrays is passed as a parameter, then the function prototype and implementation likely will have to be rewritten.

Comment: The size of arrays is not known. I am using dynamic array allocation templates in this page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21909/Introduction-to-dynamic-two-dimensional-arrays-in

Comment: @wmac then I would suggest the vector of vector approach

Comment: I have already used that method to create the arrays. It works with integers (like the example on that page). But objects of the type Agent won't work with a two dimensional dynamic array of Agent.